# Pandas Resample Quarterly data to monthly data within groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a quarterly dataframe, below:

```
ID Date     Volume Sales
1  2019-03   10     4
1  2019-06   8      6
2  2019-03   6      8
2  2019-06   4      10
```

Is there an easy way to convert this to monthly data, so that the output looks like this:

```
ID Date     Volume Sales
1  2019-01   3.33    1.33
1  2019-02   3.33    1.33
1  2019-03   3.33    1.33
1  2019-04   2.66     2
1  2019-05   2.66     2
1  2019-06   2.66     2
2  2019-01    2      2.66
2  2019-02    2      2.66
2  2019-03    2      2.66
2  2019-04    1.33   3.33
2  2019-05    1.33   3.33
2  2019-06    1.33   3.33
```

(The volume and sales column are simply divided by 3)

I have written code for this which looks like this:

```
  df = df.set_index('Date')
  df = df.groupby('ID').resample('M').bfill().reset_index()
```

Issue here is - using resampling, Q1 does not start from January as it should.

Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Can you explain the last date of the expanded data frame? Where does 2020-03 comes from?

Comment: That was an error, I have corrected it now

Comment: What is the problem with the answers given below?

Comment: Both solutions require adding, a start "date" to the code. This is not helpful in this case, as the code should only include dates provided. Is if there is another work around, without having to add new date

Comment: I updated my solution to show automatic determination of quarter start.

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution now includes automatic start date (I eliminated the 'ID' since it is irrelevant to the real problem and makes this easier to understand.)

Date functions care if you are working with the first or end of the month, and your input data only has month. Since it is quarterly results, these must be the end of the month. First we set the date on your quarterly results to the end of the quarter (since month/day will default to the first day). We resample to shift that date.

```
df = df.resample('Q', convention='end').mean()
```

Unfortunately, you can't set start or end dates on `df.resample()`, so you either add start/end dates to your data to 'fool' the resampler before resampling, or you build a new index on the dates you want. I'll take the latter approach as it's explicit and clear: You set the dates you want, and there's no ambiguity about how `pd.resample` will act with beginning and end dates.

```
start_date = data.index[0] + pd.DateOffset(months=-2) + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
end_date = data.index[-1] + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
t_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq="M"))
df= df.reindex(t_index).bfill()/3
```

This produces the result you want:

```
              Volume    Sales
2019-01-31  3.333333    1.333333
2019-02-28  3.333333    1.333333
2019-03-31  3.333333    1.333333
2019-04-30  2.666667    2.000000
2019-05-31  2.666667    2.000000
2019-06-30  2.666667    2.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the worst solution I can thing of.

Group by `ID` and add `2019 jan` manually to each group and then resample.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

def augment_group(group):
    first_row = group.iloc[[0]]
    first_row['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('2019-01')
    return first_row.append(group)

u = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
   .apply(augment_group))

res = u.set_index('Date').groupby('ID', as_index=True).resample('MS').bfill().div(3).drop('ID', axis=1).reset_index()
```

---

**res:**

```
    ID  Date        Volume      Sales
0   1   2019-01-01  3.333333    1.333333
1   1   2019-02-01  3.333333    1.333333
2   1   2019-03-01  3.333333    1.333333
3   1   2019-04-01  2.666667    2.000000
4   1   2019-05-01  2.666667    2.000000
5   1   2019-06-01  2.666667    2.000000
6   2   2019-01-01  2.000000    2.666667
7   2   2019-02-01  2.000000    2.666667
8   2   2019-03-01  2.000000    2.666667
9   2   2019-04-01  1.333333    3.333333
10  2   2019-05-01  1.333333    3.333333
11  2   2019-06-01  1.333333    3.333333
```